# "if" condition problem / question

Tags: programming, arduino-nano, c++

I'm new to Arduino and my question is rather theoretical. I have an Arduino Nano board (Atmega168 processor), a button, a display. I have written a button handler that does not stop code execution. My idea is: poll the button in "loop" cycle, and if it is pressed, perform `k++`. When `k` exceeds a specified value, perform `cnt++` and print it on the display.

Code example №1 works correctly. I get 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> ...:

```
void loop() {
 if (digitalRead(button_pd) == LOW) {
    k = k + 1;
    if (k >= 20) {
      k = 0;
      cnt = cnt + 1;
    }
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(cnt);
  }
}
```

Code example №2 is incorrect. I get 16 -> 27 -> 40 -> ... Seems like not `cnt` is printed, but `k`.

```
void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(button_pd) == LOW) {
    k = k + 1;
    if (k >= 20) {
      k = 0;
      cnt = cnt + 1;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print(cnt);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my program:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

#define button_pd 6

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

int k = 0;
int cnt = 0;

void setup() {

  pinMode(button_pd, INPUT_PULLUP);

  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(cnt);

}

void loop() {

  // button handler

}
```

My question is. Why examples №1 and №2 work differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timings are different.

Every operation on the LCD takes time. This:

```cpp
lcd.clear();
lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
lcd.print(cnt);
```

involves some I2C communication, and thus takes orders of magnitude more
time than `k++;`.

On the first version of your `loop()`, these operations are performed on
each iteration, while the button is being pressed. On the second
version, they are performed only when `k` reaches 20, thus twenty times
less often. The second version thus runs twenty times faster... too fast
for the LCD to correctly refresh and show all the values it is being
asked to display.

I recommend you do not rely on loop counting for controlling timings.
Instead, use the Arduino function specifically designed for time
management. For example, if you want to increment the counter every
200 ms, you should record the time when the button is pressed (the
falling edge of the signal), and increment `cnt` 200 ms later:

```cpp
uint8_t previous_state;  // previous state of the button
uint32_t press_timestamp;  // time when the button was pressed

void loop() {
    uint32_t now = millis();
    uint8_t state = digitalRead(button_pd);
    if (previous_state == HIGH && state == LOW)  // falling edge
        press_timestamp = now;
    previous_state = state;
    if (state == LOW && now - press_timestamp >= 200) {
        cnt = cnt + 1;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(cnt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, understood... Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, result is still incorrect. Like 0 -> 10 -> 10 -> 10 -> 21...

Comment: I've modified your code a little. Modified version worked for me. Thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Somehow code example №3 works correctly. I have used a library for timer and simplified code from the answer above.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <millisDelay.h>       // Timer

#define button_pd 6

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

int k = 0;
int cnt = 0;

//uint8_t previous_state;  // previous state of the button

millisDelay d;

void setup() {
  pinMode(button_pd, INPUT_PULLUP);

  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(cnt);
}

void loop() {

    uint8_t state = digitalRead(button_pd);
    if (state == LOW)
        d.start(300);
    //previous_state = state;
    if (d.justFinished()) {
        cnt = cnt + 1;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(cnt);
    }

}
```